# How to use `ctrl+c` in Nvim if GNOME terminal SIGINT call was remaped to ctrl+x?

Tags: copy-paste, neovim, gnome, remap

GNOME terminal SIGINT call was remaped to `ctrl+x` using `stty intr ^X`, and `ctrl+c` was maped to be 'copy'. In Neovim config I have `vim.keymap.set("v", "<C-c>", "\"+y", { noremap = true })` to be able to copy in nvim using `ctrl+c`. So now because of GNOME terminal remaps, copy in nvim with `ctrl+c` is broken. But what is interesting: copy in nvim now works with `shift+ctrl+c`. How can I deal with it? I had the same problem with `tmux` and fixed it by: `bind-key -n C-x send-keys C-c`
in tmux config. Now i think i need fix something in Nvim config. Thanks